# vim highlight current occurence of search pattern differently than `hlsearch` to help find cursor position quickely

Tags: vim

Lets say I search using `/plug` now if the `hlsearch` is on vim will highlight all the occurrence 
of keyword `plug`

now if my cursor is on the 2nd occurrence I want to highlight that differently so that i can quickly find where my cursor is

for example you can see in the following image it hard to quickly find the cursor position
[image]

Comment: you can enable the `cursorline`, it may help. The cursor is blinking right?

Comment: @Kent in the above image `cursorline` is on and in my case the cursor is not blinking  i don't know why I am using alacritty tmux and neovim if that helps

Comment: I will user `cursorline` if I can't find any answer for this will change the color of `cursorline` so that it's easy to differentiate

Comment: I tried vim8 with tmux. You are right, the cursor doesn't blick here too. I have my own config to control my cursor shape in vim, depending on different terminals. But it is not hard to find the cursor since default the cursor highlighting would be in an "inverse" way, so that it can catch our eyes easily. I guess it has something to do with your color theme. you can check `:verbose hi cursor`

Comment: btw, you can set your cursor shape too. I don't know which terminal do you use, I am using urxvt with tmux, this line makes my cursor blinking: `let &t_EI .= "\<Esc>Ptmux;\<Esc>\<Esc>[0 q\<Esc>\\"` You should read the manpage of your terninal to get the cursor shape code information.

Comment: I am using `Alacritty` terminal. wil try to check if cursor blink helps. by the way cursor color is "inverse" in my case too see the first line in the image the char 'p' is 'inverse' hilighted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [vim-searchlight](https://github.com/PeterRincker/vim-searchlight) will highlight the current search match. It does this without any mappings and works with popular plugin [vim-cool](https://github.com/romainl/vim-cool). There others as well: [vim-seachhi](https://github.com/qxxxb/vim-searchhi) & [vim-searchant](https://github.com/timakro/vim-searchant).

Comment: Thanks `vim-seachhi` looks like what I am looking for but I was hoping for a simpler config based solution but looks like there isn't any

Comment: Out of curiosity why vim-searchhi over vim-serachlight? Especially since you want a simpler configuration.

Comment: because I am not sure what `vim-searchlight` does on the documentation page it says `Vim-searchlight highlights Vim's current search match.`  what i understand by it is it only highlight current mach not rest of it but what i want is highlight current search in some other color and the rest of mach in other color also on the readme there is no image or GIF to show it's behavior

Comment: Here is an [example of vim-searchlight](https://asciinema.org/a/297040)

Comment: ooh then searchlight is what I will use awesome thanks