# In vim, how do I change the highlight color of the currently highlighted search term?

Tags: vim

From [Fandom](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Highlight_all_search_pattern_matches):

> With the defaults, setting this option causes all text matching the
>   current search to be highlighted using the Search highlight group,
>   which adds a **yellow background** to the current highlighting.

`hi Search` will change the color of matching patterns in vim, but not the currently selected search term, which has an unreadable yellow background. How can I change this currently selected background to something else? What's the `hi ###` term?

Comment: `hi IncSearch`?

Comment: Yep. Perfect. Thanks :)

Comment: Semi-related post: [vim highlight current occurence of search pattern differently than `hlsearch` to help find cursor position quickely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60001808/438329)

Answer (score 9):

The option is called `IncSearch` so the line will look something like this:

```
hi IncSearch cterm=NONE ctermfg=yellow ctermbg=green
```

It is possible to look at the colorschemes in the `$VIMRUNTIME/colors/*.vim` files of the machine.

Comment: FYI, CurSearch was added somewhat recently (See this [discussion](https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/10133)).